# How to reload nginx config only on part of workers?

Tags: nginx

Is there any way to prevent nginx from reloading configuration on all workers at the same time? I have configured some really short timeouts, so doubling number of workers processes when load is high causes raise of 504 errors. I want to prevent that by exchanging workers one by one (or maybe three by three), but I cannot find any way to achieve that.

**Edit:**

During configuration reload nginx doubles number of worker processes:

[image]

CDN I was developing was making requests during computation of cache keys. These request had really short timeouts (50ms if I remember correctly), so they were very sensitive for changes of servers' loads. When configuration reloads were frequent these requests were timing out. I assumed that it was caused by additional worker processes so I was wondering if it is possible to reload configuration only on few workers at the same time. It could work like this:

- create ***n*** workers with new configuration
- stop assigning new connections to ***n*** workers with old configuration
- wait until these ***n*** old workers exit gracefully
- repeat this process until there is no more workers with old configuration

I didn't found any option which enables such behaviour so I assume that it isn't possible. But I want to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you misunderstands nginx' design.

This Web server is not following the one-process-per-connection classical scheme as Apache, for one, does.

Thus, there is little to no use in adding more workers than you number of CPU cores, a number of worker process being equal to this machine property being the most efficient configuration.

Put another way: in Apache times, you *had* to add more workers to handle more traffic since 1 process <=> 1 connection.

Now, this nginx, only the relation 1 connection => 1 process remains, but 1 process => 1 connection is not true anymore. The event-driven design of nginx allows each worker to accept many connections instead of waiting (remaining idle) until he is totally busy (100% CPU on the core-s- being used).

The baseline is: you do not need to change the number of workers of your nginx instance if it is properly configured (cf. [`worker_processes`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#worker_processes), `auto` being usually enough). If the workers are all saturated, then you will have a machine property being the bottleneck (CPU, I/O), thus adding new workers won't do much but add to the problem.

Now, for the part in which you want to 'exchange workers one by one', nginx' master allocate sockets to workers, so you would not know which requests/clients you are affecting.

Think of if at a group which spawns (and dies) together. You could have several binary version and/or several configuration loaded on several masters at the same time by using the [on-the-fly upgrade](http://nginx.org/en/docs/control.html#upgrade) capability of nginx. You can then switch between different configuration seamlessly and almost instantly by communicating with the masters through signals.

I **strongly** suggest you read on [nginx' design](https://www.nginx.com/blog/inside-nginx-how-we-designed-for-performance-scale/) to have a clear idea of what you are dealing with and why what you asks falls flat.

You have not specified what your real intent is, so I was stuck with providing you with the exact questions you asked. There is probably a simpler set of questions/answers if you told the community what you wanted to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I've read article you suggested before asking this question.